# Annotation @Metered and @Timed

Tags: jax-rs, codahale-metrics

In dropwizard-metric I saw them being mentioned @Metered and @Timed annotation. I try to use that in some restful services with JAX-RS. Where I can found some simple and concrete example of using that annotation?